# Censored model JAGS count data

Tags: hierarchy, bayesian, poisson, jags, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm coding a hierarchical Poisson model in JAGS+R for count data for censored data.

A is a matrix, rows are the different places and the columns are the different time intervals in which I count the rainy days. As covariates I have a set of X_k$ matrices. For every place and time interval I have covariates such as mean temperature (stored in X_1), count of windy days (in X_2), mean humidity (in X_3).

Should I separate the censored data from the non censored ones? How do I do that with matrices?

Thanks for your help!

Update:

I have this in a cycle up to the last but one registered time interval (for each place there might be censoring due to equipment failure)

mu[i,j]<- a[1]*x[i,1]+a[2]*x[i,2]+ b[1,j]*varx[i,j]+b[2,j]*varx[i,j]            
N[i,j] <- dpois(lambda[i,j]) 
log(lambda[i,j]) <- mu[i,j]  + alpha[i] 
alpha[i]<- G0[latent[i]] 
latent[i]~ dcat(prob[])

repeated this for the last time interval. Added 
censoor[i]<-step(-censored[i]) 
 in the last time interval bit, censored[i] is a vec that indicates if there is an equipment failure

I am new & it doesn't work, any help? Thanks

Comment: Store the data however you want, just make sure you tell JAGS where to find each bit of data it needs.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/290984/censored-data-poisson-model-jags and very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476162/jags-poisson-count-censored-data in that the topic is the same (and I guess it relates to the same model). Please do not cross post without at least a note that you have done so.  Your questions also need to be more specific - i.e. not 'how can I code this', but 'I've tried this code but don't understand why it fails'. At the moment your question can really only be answered with a link to a book or (lengthy) tutorial.

Comment: I will code and post if it fails and I don't understand why.
I also would appreciate a link to a book or a lenght tutorial however, very much so. I am quite stuck atm. Thanks!

Comment: I can recommend this book as a general introduction to Bayesian models:  https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/

Comment: I have this in a cycle up to the last but one registered time interval (for each place there might be censoring due to equipment failure) <br/>

mu[i,j]<- a[1]*x[i,1]+a[2]*x[i,2]+ b[1,j]*varx[i,j]+b[2,j]*varx[i,j]   <br/>
N[i,j] <- dpois(lambda[i,j]) <br/>
log(lambda[i,j]) <- mu[i,j]  + alpha[i] <br/>
alpha[i]<- G0[latent[i]] <br/>
latent[i]~ dcat(prob[])   


 repeated this for the last time interval. Added censoor[i]<-step(-censored[i]) in the last time interval bit, censored[i] is a vec that indicates if there is an equipment failure

I am new & it doesn't work, any help? Thanks